# adding properties to custom classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create my own UIImageView handler. I managed to subclass the touch events necessary. I haven't figured out how to add my own properties. I'd like to add a UIColor property to set the stroke color for my handlers. Here's the .h file.

```
//
//  imageViewController.h
//  slate
//
//  Created by House of Pawn on 11/15/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ma. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imageViewController : UIImageView

@end
```

Here's the .m file

```
//
//  imageViewController.m
//  slate
//
//  Created by House of Pawn on 11/15/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ma. All rights reserved.
//

#import "imageViewController.h"

@interface imageViewController ()



@end

@implementation imageViewController
CGPoint lastPoint;
CGFloat red;
CGFloat green;

NSString const *key = @"my.very.unique.key";

CGFloat blue;
CGFloat brush;
CGFloat opacity;
UIColor* strokeColor;
BOOL mouseSwiped;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //  [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 //   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    mouseSwiped = NO;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    NSLog(@"Touches Began");
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);

    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 30.0 );


    CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(_strokeColor.CGColor);


    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), components[0], components[1], components[2], 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self setAlpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}




- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 14.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

}





@end
```

I need to be able to pass my custom UIImageView controller class a UIColor like I said above. The variable i'd like to use is stroke color. I've seen posts about using categories but they make no sense to me. If someone can help me implement this it'd be great.

Comment: FYI - All of those variables in your .m file are global variables. Those are *not* instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Customise the control, you should use IBInspectable & IBDesignable

For Objective C:
use this Link : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/ib-designable-custom-views-in-interface-builder/

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface imageViewController : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *strokeColor;

@end
```

For Swift:
use this Link: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

```
@IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor? {
   didSet {
       layer.borderColor = borderColor?.CGColor
   }
}
```

Thank You.